# Chrome Extension - using commands (keyboard shortcuts) with num pad

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to implement keyboard shortcuts into a Chrome extension.

I have managed this, but I'd like to have a keyboard shortcut that makes use of the num pad rather than the numbers along the top (well, in addition to).

Below is my manifest and script.

Perhaps this is a limitation of Chrome commands.

manifest.json

```
{
    "name": "Shortcut Test",
    "version": "1",
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "background": {"scripts": ["background.js"]},
    "commands": {
        "shortcut_test": {
            "suggested_key": {
                "default": "Ctrl+0",
        "windows": "Ctrl+0"
            },
            "description": "A test shortcut"
        }
    }
}
```

background.js

```
chrome.commands.onCommand.addListener(function(command){
    console.log(command);
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Yep, commands currently has a very limited key selection. Just normal letters and numbers.

Comment: Do you have a reference for this? I can't find the relevant documentation.

Comment: Way back then I had to dig through the code for it. I don't know if it is documented or possibly even changed now.